# Работа с функциями. как передать коллекцию в функции?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать данный код? Как сделать такие функции? (данный код менять нельзя)

- friends - массив, состоящий из объектов
- select, filterIn - функции, результатом которых является работа над коллекцией friends

Вот как friends занести в функции select и filterIn

```
var bestFriends = lib.query(
  friends,
  lib.select('name', 'gender', 'email'),
  lib.filterIn('favoriteFruit', ['Яблоко', 'Картофель'])
);
```

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. А то не понятно, что собственно нужно и с чем возникли затруднения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> select, filterIn - функции, результатом которых является работа над коллекцией friends

Не совсем так. Функции `.select()` и `.filterIn()` - это функции, результатом которых будут функции, которые будут работать над коллекцией `friends`

Функция `.query()` получает на вход

- коллекцию `friends`,
- функцию выбора полей из коллекции `friends`, полученную в результате выполнения `lib.select('name', 'gender', 'email')`
- функцию фильтрации элементов из коллекции `friends`, полученную в результате выполнения `lib.filterIn('favoriteFruit', ['Яблоко', 'Картофель'])`

---

Примерный код

```js
var lib = {
  query: function (data, select, filter) {
    return select(filter(data))
  },
  select: function (...fields) {
    return function (data) {
      return data.map(function (x) {
        var item = {}
        fields.forEach(function (field) {
          item[field] = x[field]
        })
        return item
      })
    }
  },
  filterIn: function (field, values) {
    return function (data) {
      return data.filter(function (x) {
        return values.indexOf(x[field]) > -1
      })
    }
  }
}

var friends = [
  {
    name: 'Михаил',
    gender: 'муж',
    email: 'mikhail@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Тыква'
  },
  {
    name: 'Алексей',
    gender: 'муж',
    email: 'aleksey@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Дыня'
  },
  {
    name: 'Федор',
    gender: 'муж',
    email: 'fedor@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Яблоко'
  },
  {
    name: 'Иван',
    gender: 'муж',
    email: 'ivan@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Мандарин'
  },
  {
    name: 'Петр',
    gender: 'муж',
    email: 'petr@example.com',
    favoriteFruit: 'Картофель'
  }
]

var bestFriends = lib.query(
  friends,
  lib.select('name', 'gender', 'email'),
  lib.filterIn('favoriteFruit', ['Яблоко', 'Картофель'])
);

console.log(bestFriends)
```